# Mongoose Populate Array of ObjectIDs that utilizes refPath returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

issue.js

```
const mongoose;
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    docs: {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        refPath: 'coll',
        required: true
    },
    coll: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Product', 'Service']
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Issue', schema);
```

partial index.js

```
try{
    let issues = await Issue.find().populate('docs');

    console.log(issues);
    //every issue in issues, has an empty 'docs' array, when it should consist of products/services that exist

}catch(e){}
```

Not sure why arrays is making it not work, I tried making the docs field as singular ObjectId, and it worked fine. Only thing I could think of is that because it's an array, the refPath has to be different, but I'm not sure what I could add, as I tried using 'this.coll'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an error in your schema. Not sure if that is the issue, but you can try.

```
const mongoose;
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    docs: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // <-- This line
        refPath: 'coll',
        required: true
    }],
    coll: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Product', 'Service']
    }
});
```

Comment: That was to make it an array of ObjectIds, not a single 1. Oh but that helped me debug it! I had to do the Square Brackets around the whole docs object, not just the type! Thanks! :)

Comment: @DarrenA. Yeah. Updated my answer to support array.